# MySQL general_log only shows a hex number instead of SQL?

Tags: mysql, query, table, logs, logging

When I enable sql logging to table like this:

```
set global log_output = 'table'
set global general_log = 'on'
```

Do some queries then look at the log table like this:

```
select * from mysql.general_log 
order by event_time desc
```

I don't see my sql. I see hex numbers like this in the argument field or blank ('') and no SQL at all:

> 0x53484F5720435245415445205441424C4520606D7973716C602E6067656E6572616C5F6C6F6760

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this query to get the argument as text:

```
select a.*, convert(a.argument using utf8) from general_log a;
```

Answer (score 3):

This query below shows **the human readable query logs of `argument` column**:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(argument USING utf8) FROM mysql.general_log;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the hexadecimal representation of the query ASCII string:

```
$ python -c 'print "53484F5720435245415445205441424C4520606D7973716C602E6067656E6572616C5F6C6F6760".decode("hex")'
SHOW CREATE TABLE `mysql`.`general_log`
```

If you check the output of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command which you apparently executed, you'll see that the `argument` column data type is `mediumblob`, which is a binary format and is therefore printed as a hex string.

`mysql` CLI should translate such strings automatically; I suspect the client software you're using is not doing that.